# find the adjoint of an operator defined by trace

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question:**

Given this inner product, 
$\langle A, B\rangle = \operatorname{tr}(B^* A)$
and $V=M_n (\Bbb C)$. $T_P(x)=P^{-1}XP$ . Find $T_p^*$

**What I did**
let $X\in M_n(\Bbb C)$.
I've noticed that If I take $T(I)$ I get this interesting result:
$<T(I),X>=<I,T^*(X)>$ (from the adjoint definition)
$<T(I),X>=<P^{-1}IP,X>=<I,X>=tr(X^*)=<I,T^*(X)>$

from the last equality is it true to say that $T_P^*(X)=X$?

Comment: The identity map is self adjoint (for very obvious reasons), so you are definitely wrong in your last guess. You can't just do the whole thing with only the identity matrix, you need to replace $I$ by something arbitrary! Did you see it thorough?

Comment: @Patrick: $P^{-1}IP=I$.

Comment: @Martin : I was mentally computing as if the matrix $I$ was arbitrary, so it took me a while to realize he/she was doing this with the identity matrix, which was precisely the mistake...

Comment: ... Well I got so close to the given answer below... This is so confusing. Thanx everyone....

Comment: @user1685224 Don't worry about it, it'll keep happening as long as you do math! Happens to all of us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to find $T_P^*$ such that for all $X,Y$,
$$\mathrm{Tr}(X^*T_P^*(Y))=\mathrm{Tr}(T_P(X)^*Y)=\mathrm{Tr}(P^*X^*P^{-*}Y).$$
Noting that
$$\mathrm{Tr}(P^*X^*P^{-*}Y)=\mathrm{Tr}(X^*P^{-*}YP^*)$$
we get that
$$T_P^*(Y)=P^{-*}YP^*.$$

Edit: Note that $P^{-*}:=(P^{-1})^*=(P^*)^{-1}$.

Comment: yay, $P^{-*}$ :D $P$ to the minus star!

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva I thought this was standard notation for $(P^{-1})^*=(P^*)^{-1}$. Is it not?

Comment: Never heard of it (and I never "have" to write $(P^{-1})^*$ in my life, so don't consider me a reference), but the idea "$P$ to the minus star" made a funny noise in my head :D I liked it

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva To be honest I made the notation up, but I assumed it was standard since I see $P^{-T}$ pretty often with real matrices.

Comment: It is definitely not standard in the literature I know of. That said, it is a lot better than $(P^{-1})^*$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Maybe I'm a trend setter then!

Answer (score 1):

Let $X, Y \in M_n(\mathbb C)$. Then
$$
\langle T_P(X), Y \rangle = \langle P^{-1}XP, Y \rangle = \mathrm{tr}( Y^*(P^{-1}XP)) = \mathrm{tr}((Y^*P^{-1}XP)^*) = \mathrm{tr}(P^*X^* (P^*)^{-1} Y) = \mathrm{tr}(X^* (P^*)^{-1} YP^*) = \langle (P^*)^{-1} Y P^*,X \rangle
$$
so I'd say $T^*_P = T_{P^*}$.

Comment: I didn't understand the last passage, how does it fit with the inner product space that was defined? isn't it supposed to equal <...,X> and not the opposite?

Comment: @user1685224 : I corrected it, but what I wrote was still correct since $\langle A,B \rangle = \langle B,A \rangle$ because the trace of a matrix is equal to the trace of its transpose, hence $\mathrm{tr}(A^*B) = \mathrm{tr}(B^*A)$. Anyway, fixed it.